# I think the author's argument in Addenda is unnecessarily complicated. (Sard's Theorem. "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

> **3-14. Theorem (Sard's Theorem).** Let $g:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable, where $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and let $B=\{x\in A:\det g'(x)=0\}$. Then $g(B)$ has measure $0$.

> Proof. Let $U\subset A$ be a closed rectangle such that all sides of $U$ have length $l$, say. Let $\varepsilon>0$. If $N$ is sufficiently large and $U$ is divided into $N^n$ rectangles, with sides of length $\frac{l}{N}$, then for each of these rectangles $S$, if $x\in S$ we have $$|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)-g(x)|<\varepsilon|x-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N}$$ for all $y\in S$.

In Addenda, the author wrote as follows:

> The argument in the first part of Theorem 3-14 (Sard's Theorem) requires a little amplification. If $U\subset A$ is a closed rectangle with sides of length $l$, then, because $U$ is compact, there is an integer $N$ with the following property: if $U$ is divided into $N^n$ rectangles, with sides of length $\frac{l}{N}$, then $|D_jg^i(w)-D_jg^i(z)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}$ whenever $w$ and $z$ are both in one such rectangle $S$. Given $x\in S$, let $f(z)=Dg(x)(z)-g(z)$. Then if $z\in S$, $$|D_jf^i(z)|=|D_jg^i(x)-D_jg^i(z)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}.$$ So by Lemma 2-10, if $x,y\in S$, then $$|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)+g(x)|=|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon |x-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N}.$$

My questions are here:

1. I think the inequality $$|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)-g(x)|<\varepsilon|x-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N}$$ in the proof of Theorem 3-14 is wrong.
   I think the inequality $$|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)+g(x)|<\varepsilon|x-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N}$$ is right. (This inequality is the same as the inequality in Addenda.)
   Am I right?
2. Why did the author write Addenda?
   Since $g$ is continuously differentiable, $g$ is differentiable at $x\in S$.
   So, if $N$ is sufficiently large, then $\frac{|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)+g(x)|}{|x-y|}<\varepsilon$ for all $y\in S$ such that $y\neq x$.
   So, $|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)+g(x)|\leq\varepsilon|x-y|$ holds for all $y\in S$ such that $y\neq x$.
   Of course, this inequality holds for $y=x$.
   I think the author's argument in Addenda is unnecessarily complicated.
   Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $x\in U$, there is an integer $N_x$ such that if $U$ is divided into $N_{x}^{n}$ rectangles, with sides of length $\frac{l}{N_x}$ and if $x$ is in some rectangle $S_x$, then we have $|Dg(x)(y-x)-g(y)+g(x)|<\varepsilon |x-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N_x}$ for all $y\in S_x$.

For another $z\in U$, there is a subrectangle $S_z$ such that $z\in S_z$.
But unfortunately, in general, we cannot say $|Dg(z)(y-z)-g(y)+g(z)|<\varepsilon |z-y|\leq\varepsilon\sqrt{n}\frac{l}{N_x}$ for all $y\in S_z$ by your argument.

So, the argument in Addenda is necessary.